# How to ensure remotely-fetched images in UITableView cells always filled?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimage, remote-server

I have gotten this question several times in job interviews: You have a UITableView and the user is scrolling very fast. How exactly do you make sure at all of the cells' images which are being loaded from a server are visible wherever the user scrolls to.

I can think of several techniques. For instance what I have done is use an operation queue, loaded with requests to fetch images, and when the user starts scrolling, empty the queue and fill it with requests for images wherever the user is going towards.

Another solution is to fill the images with super-low-resolution thumbnails e.g. a 4-point gradient so that some image, albeit a bad one, is there long before the real image arrives.

Answer (score 0):

I would say "empty the queue and fill it with requests for images wherever the user is going towards" is correct using `indexPathsForVisibleRows`. But the images will never appear immediately unless they are very small.

I think what they mean is to show the downloaded image immediately after it has been downloaded from the background thread, which would be: `dispatch_get_main_queue()`

In .h file:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

In .m file:

```
- (void)downloadVisibleRowImages
{
    NSArray *visibleRows = [self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void) {
        for (NSIndexPath *visibleRow in visibleRows) {
            UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: visibleRow];
            NSString *imageUrl = [_responseImages objectAtIndex:visibleRow.row];
            UIImage *image = nil; // Download image here
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ // use main thread to display image immediately after download
                if (image) [cell.imageView setImage:image];
            });
        }
    });
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    if (!decelerate) {
        [self downloadVisibleRowImages];
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [self downloadVisibleRowImages];
}
```

Comment: Cool that helps. I was not aware of indexPathsForVisibleRows until now.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the key here is "wherever the user scrolls to". Because of that, you shouldn't start downloading images until you know which cells are going to be visible.

So what I would do is watch for the UIScrollViewDelegate call:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

At that point, get the cells visible using:

```
- (NSArray *)indexPathsForVisibleRows
```

And then spin off my downloads for images. Putting it all together:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    NSArray *theIndexPaths = [self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
    for (NSIndexPath *theIndexPath in theIndexPaths) {
        SomeObject *myObject = self.listOfMyObjects[theIndexPath.row];
        [myObject downloadImage];
    }
}
```

This is very basic. Obviously need to update the cell, etc.

Comment: I agree. My experience has been that when I start making requests during scrolling that the scrolling becomes choppy. But the moment and I remove the call to the routine that makes requests, the scrolling become smooth again. It would be nice if I could make requesting scrolling based on a calculation of where the scrolling well end based on the current momentum, however that appears to be impossible because of the choppiness.